# How to initialize Objects when implementing interface

Tags: java

I have an `Interface` called Reduction with the following:

```
public interface Reduction{
    double taxReduction();
}
```

Now i have 3 different classes called `User`, `Taxpayer` and `Company`.
`Taxpayer` and `Company` extend from `User` and contain the body of the method in the `Interface`, taxReduction.

What i want to do now is be able to initialize Taxpayer and Company on my main. In the beggining, when i defined the method `taxReduction` i was getting an error saying Taxpayer was not abstract, so i added that to the class Taxpayer:

```
public abstract class Taxpayer implements Reduction{
   ...
}
```

After that, i tried to initialize Taxpayer on my main and i was getting an error saying it could not be initialized because Taxpayer was abstract. Since i need get my app registering users i have the following:

```
User u = new User();
```

Then i get all the input from the user and i simple do:

```
u = (User) new Taxpayer(all the variables i got) // if it's a Taxpayer user.
```

In this i get the error that i stated above. As you can see i don't really need to work with the method on the Interface, just to be able to create new `Users`. How can i solve this?

Comment: Your interface will not compile. Did you mean to make `taxReduction` a method?

Comment: I'm missing two () after the double taxReduction, but just in here, it was a typo. I had them on my Interface. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, the method is already defined in both Taxpayer and Company.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot initialize abstract class.

The correct interface should be:

```
public interface Reduction{
    double taxReduction();
}
```

And your `TaxPayer` should provide a body for that method:

```
public class Taxpayer implement Reduction {

      @Override
      double taxReduction() {
           // If sons > 4 then return 10% etc
      }
}
```

**Edit**

To @EJP: here are the words of wisdom from [Java document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated

Comment: I'm missing two () after the double taxReduction, but just in here, it was a typo. I had them on my Interface. Sorry about that.

Comment: The body is already defined for the method, both in Taxpayer and Company. My problem is in the main.

Comment: If you already provide body for `TaxPayer`, it should not `abstract` anymore.remove that keyword

Comment: Certainly you can initialize an abstract class. Just provide the appropriate constructor. You cannot *instantiate* it.

Comment: @EJP If you initialize the abstract class via new, you already create an anonymous class  which implements the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

You interface Reduction doesn't contains method, you have to put () after method name as:

```
public interface Reduction{
    double taxReduction();
}
```

A class implementing an interface must provide implementation for all of its method unless it’s an abstract class. So, this class needs to implement method of interface Reduction else it will be Abstract:

```
public abstract class Taxpayer implements Reduction{
   ...
}
or 
public class Taxpayer implements Reduction
{
double taxreduction()
{
.....
}
}
```

Comment: Yes the missing () was a typo, i had them on my Interface. The body is already defined for the method, both in Taxpayer and Company. My problem is in the main.

Comment: @Joao Amorim see the explanation

Comment: @JoãoAmorim did you get what you want to do?

Comment: I understand what you were saying, but i already have all of that. In the meantime i actually discovered where my error was. On my main i was doing: `User u = new User();`. After changing it to User u = null; it started working.